Helgason Theorem III.4.3(iii) proof
The following are from Helgason's "Differential geometry, Lie groups, and symmetric spaces."

($\S$III.4 p.165-). In $\S$4 and $\S$5 let $\mathfrak g$ be an arbitrary semisimple Lie algebra over $\mathbb C$ and let $\mathfrak h$ denote an arbitrary fixed Cartan subalgebra.
Let $\alpha$ be a linear function on the complex vector space $\mathfrak h$. Let $\mathfrak g^\alpha$ denote the linear subspace of $\mathfrak g$ given by
\begin{equation}
\mathfrak g^\alpha=\{X\in\mathfrak g:\text{$[H,X]=\alpha(H)X$ for all $H\in\mathfrak h$}\}\text.
\end{equation}
The linear function $\alpha$ is called a root (of $\mathfrak g$ with respect to $\mathfrak h$) if $\mathfrak g^\alpha\neq\{0\}$. In that case, $\mathfrak g^\alpha$ is called a root subspace. Since $\mathfrak h$ is a maximal abelian subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$ we have $\mathfrak g^0=\mathfrak h$. From the Jacobi identity we obtain easily the relation
\begin{equation}
[\mathfrak g^\alpha,\mathfrak g^\beta]\subset\mathfrak g^{\alpha+\beta}
\end{equation}
for any pair $\alpha,\beta$ of $\mathbb C$-linear functions on $\mathfrak h$.
Let $\Delta$ denote the set of all nonzero roots and as before let $B$ denote the Killing form on $\mathfrak g\times\mathfrak g$.


Theorem III.4.2.
(i) $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak h+\sum_{\alpha\in\Delta}\mathfrak g^\alpha$ (direct sum).
(ii) $\dim\mathfrak g^\alpha=1$ for each $\alpha\in\Delta$.
(iii) Let $\alpha,\beta$ be two roots such that $\alpha+\beta\neq0$. Then $\mathfrak g^\alpha$ and $\mathfrak g^\beta$ are orthogonal under $B$.
(iv) The restriction of $B$ to $\mathfrak h\times\mathfrak h$ is nondegenerate. For each linear form $\alpha$ on $\mathfrak h$ there exists a unique element $H_\alpha\in\mathfrak h$ such that
\begin{equation}
B(H,H_\alpha)=\alpha(H)\qquad\text{for all $H\in\mathfrak h$.}
\end{equation}
We put $\langle\lambda,\mu\rangle=B(H_\lambda,H_\mu)$.
(v) If $\alpha\in\Delta$, then $-\alpha\in\Delta$ and
\begin{equation}
[\mathfrak g^\alpha,\mathfrak g^{-\alpha}]=\mathbb CH_\alpha\text,\qquad\alpha(H_\alpha)\neq0\text.
\end{equation}


Proof. (Omitted.)


Let $\alpha\in\Delta$ and let $\beta$ be any root. The $\alpha$-series containing $\beta$ is by definition the set of all roots of the form $\beta+n\alpha$ where $n$ is an integer.


Theorem III.4.3. Let $\beta$ be a root, and $\alpha\in\Delta$.
(i) The $\alpha$-series containing $\beta$ has the form $\beta+n\alpha$ ($p\leq n\leq q$) (the $\alpha$-series is an uninterrupted string). Also
\begin{equation}
-2\frac{\beta(H_\alpha)}{\alpha(H_\alpha)}=p+q\text.
\end{equation}
(ii) (Omitted.)
(iii) The only roots proportional to $\alpha$ are $-\alpha,0,\alpha$.
(iv) (Omitted.)


Proof. (Proof of (i) omitted.) For (iii) let $n\alpha$ ($p\leq n\leq q$) be the $\alpha$-series containing $0$. The subspace
\begin{equation}
\color{red}{\mathfrak s=\sum_{n=-1}^q\mathfrak g^{n\alpha}}
\end{equation}
$\color{red}{\textrm{is then invariant under $\operatorname{ad}E_{-\alpha}$}}$, $\operatorname{ad}E_\alpha$, and $\operatorname{ad}H_\alpha$. We find as before
\begin{equation}
0=\operatorname{Tr}_{\mathfrak s}\operatorname{ad}H_\alpha=\sum_{n=-1}^qn\alpha(H_\alpha)\text,
\end{equation}
which implies $q=1$. Using Theorem 4.2 (v), we see that $p=-1$. (The rest omitted.)

Why is the red part true? $\mathfrak s$ is indeed invariant if $n=-1$ is replaced by $n=p$, but why does $n=-1$ work?

The key point is that $[E_{-\alpha}, E_{-\alpha}] = 0$ and $\mathfrak{g}_{-\alpha}$ is spanned by $E_{-\alpha}$ (by definition of $E_{-\alpha}$), so $[E_{-\alpha}, \mathfrak{g}_{-\alpha}] = 0$.
